# Can I reduce to 0 seconds the PreviewScreen(White) time at the start?

Tags: android, performance, android-lifecycle

There's a white-blank screen in android, just before the launch screen, at the start of the Application, that white-blank screen it's about 2 seconds in devices like Samsung j1 with android 5.1. That 2 seconds it's due to the app performance or the Android and hardware performance, that 2 seconds can be reduced?.

We make up the problem using the following in our app theme: `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>`, that means that the white screen now it's transparent, so it seems to be an Android problem from the user perspective, but it's a way to reduce the time of this preview screen to a half or near zero?

Reference to this problem in:

1. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time
2. [Android - Disable dummy starting window of application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922915/android-disable-dummy-starting-window-of-application)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905317/how-can-i-remove-white-screen-which-appear-before-splash-screenhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437037/android-prevent-white-screen-at-startup
4. https://www.tothenew.com/blog/disabling-the-preview-or-start-window-in-android/
5. [blank screen comes before splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342933/blank-screen-comes-before-splash)

Comment: Do less stuff on the UI thread on application start

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the startup guidelines and performance measurement techniques here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

This will tell you where the time is being spent during startup and give you suggestions on how to improve that.

Also, you can provide a splash screen that shows instead of the white screen. See details here:

https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565